# Why does a list of arguments wrapped in braces return the last argument?

Tags: javascript

I'm correcting some basic Javascript assignments and a student has stumped me with this particular line in a constructor:

```
this.c = (255, 255, 255);
```

I'd like to explain to them (and to myself) why this statement, or any like it, will evaluate to the last 'argument' given.

```
console.log( ("foo", 42, {}, NaN) )  --> NaN
console.log( ("foo", 42, {}) )       --> Object
console.log( ("foo", 42) )           --> Number
console.log( ("foo") )               --> String
console.log( () )                    --> SyntaxError // no longer the same thing
```

In the case of their assignment, they use that property as an RGB value, yet only stick to monochrome and thus their code still functions as intended. I'd like to know what that statement is called (if it has a name?) and what's happening in terms of the JS spec that has it behaving like so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: "The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand."

Comment: @Pointy Perfect, many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the [*comma operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). It's an unusual operator: It evaluates its left-hand operand, throws that value away, evaluates its right-hand operand, and uses the result as its result value. You sometimes see it used where evaluating the first operand has a side-effect:

```js
const a = (console.log("foo"), 42);
console.log(a);
```

The MDN page linked above is *slightly* inaccurate, suggesting that the comma operator accepts more than two operands. It doesn't, it's a binary operator (it accepts two operands); it's just that it's left-to-right associative, so

```
const a = (1, 2, 3);
```

is the same as

```
const a = ((1, 2), 3);
```

Comment: Very cool - and unusual. The use in a for loop seems obvious now. Cheers!!

Comment: @MichaelHemingway - Indeed! :-) Often, the use in a `for` loop isn't the comma operator (e.g.: `for (var l = a.length; i = 0; i < l; ++i)`) where it's the `var` statement (similar but different), but other times it is indeed the comma operator (e.g., `for (l = a.length, i = 0; i < l; ++i)`, the only difference being the lack of `var, or `for (var i = 0, j = a.length; i < j; ++i, --j)`).